# Angular Directive - focus back to first attribute element

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am adding a directive for focus setting. in case of `focus-able` element will be identified by it's data as `[attr.focus]="true"`  for example I have 2 buttons with attribute added.

on directive load, the first element focusing. but when the user `blurs` the last element, I would like to take him back to first element. until i get an enter from the element. my directive not works for it. i try with `addEventListener` with children.

how to handle this?

```
import { AfterContentInit, Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[autoFocus]'
})
export class AutofocusDirective implements AfterContentInit {
  @Input() public autoFocus: boolean;
  selector = `[focus="true"]`;
  dealy: number;

  public constructor(private readonly el: ElementRef) {
    this.dealy = 100;
  }

  public ngAfterContentInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const focus = this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(this.selector);
      const first = focus[0];
      const last = focus[focus.length - 1];
      if (first) {
        first.focus();
      }

      last.nativeElement.addEventListner('blur', () => {
        first.focus();
      });
    }, this.dealy); //not works!!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to log the focus elements to find out if this is really finding the two buttons.

```
const focus = this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(this.selector);
console.log({focus});
```

You wrote you applied the attribute to the two buttons, but because you are searching with `this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll` the elements below the one with the attribute I would suggest to replace it with `document.querySelectorAll`.

Another solution could be to distinguish between a root directive, that searches for elements within with another directive.